# Invoke a MVC Action from a Button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

*First I want to know is it compulsory to have a view made for each and every Action method in a controller?

*How to Invoke a Action method in MVC4 when a button is clicked in  another view? Do i need to have a view made for the Action method that I'm gonna invoke by pressing the button which is in another view.

*Here is my code*

**CustomerController**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/
        List<Customer> CustomerCollection = new List<Customer>();
        public CustomerController()
        {

            Customer cus = new Customer();
            cus.CustomerId = 1;
            cus.Name = "dath";
            cus.Gender = "Male";
            cus.City = "Csmbo";
            CustomerCollection.Add(cus);

            cus = new Customer();
            cus.CustomerId = 2;
            cus.Name = "Jacob";
            cus.Gender = "FeMale";
            cus.City = "Cosbo";
            CustomerCollection.Add(cus);

            cus = new Customer();
            cus.CustomerId = 3;
            cus.Name = "Gags";
            cus.Gender = "Male";
            cus.City = "NewYork";
            CustomerCollection.Add(cus);
        }
        public ActionResult GetCustomerList()
        {

            return View(CustomerCollection);
        }
        public ActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            var selectedCustomer = CustomerCollection.Where(p => p.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(selectedCustomer);
        }
```

**This is the Action method im gonna invoke by Pressing the button in the view called DeleteCustomer. For this Action method I haven't created any View**

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult DeleteCus(int id)
            {
                var selectedCustomer = CustomerCollection.Where(o => o.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                CustomerCollection.Remove(selectedCustomer);
                RedirectToAction("GetCustomerList", "Customer");
                return View();
            }
```

**This is the DeleteCustomer Action method**

```
public ActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {

            var selectedCustomer = CustomerCollection.Where(a => a.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(selectedCustomer);
    }
```

**Finally this is the DeleteCustomer view that im passing the Customer seleted in DeleteCustomer Action method. And The Button is in this view. from this button i need to invoke the DeleteCus Action method(so it will remove the seleted Customer from the customerCollection List**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<myapp12.Models.Customer>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DeleteCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>

        <div class="display-label">
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender) %>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender) %>
        </div>

        <div class="display-label">
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City) %>
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City) %>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteCus", "Customer", new { id = Model.CustomerID })'"/>
     <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "GetCustomerList")%>
        </p>
    <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

**The thing that i have used in onClick event is not working. I need it to work so that selected Customer can be deleted.**

Comment: Are you sure `CustomerCollection.Remove(selectedCustomer);` deletes the customer from database and not just from collection? If you have no View you can call `return Content("Hi there!");` instead of `return View();`

Comment: @keiv.fly Hi im not using a Database im just making objects and storing them in the list and showing them back from the list

Comment: Then how does the list persist from page to page? Where is the list created?

Comment: Can anyone please show me a sample code?

Comment: @keiv.fly List has been created inside the CustomerController class and values have been assigned in CustomerController Constructor.

Comment: Webpages suppose that if you create data on page load all data dies after the page is given. Only database and things like memcached can live between the page calls.

Comment: Constructor is loaded each time the page is loaded.

Comment: If my solution solved your problem can you mark my Answer?

Comment: But still I didn't get the answer

Comment: You should store your data in a database.

Comment: Alright I will But Can you tell me a way to invoke a action method from a button? have i done that part correct in my sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data in a database, otherwise you cannot save changes.

If your data is created in collections in controller constructor it should all die when the page is given and created each time the page is loaded. Database data and things like memcached persist between page calls, usual variable do not.

Here is the code without View. But remove will not work as soon as CustomerCollection is a usual variable.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteCus(int id)
{
    var selectedCustomer = CustomerCollection.Where(o => o.CustomerId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    CustomerCollection.Remove(selectedCustomer);
    return RedirectToAction("GetCustomerList", "Customer");
}
```

Comment: Can you give me  a simple code to call a action from a button

Comment: Okay Thanks But why Returning a RedirectToAction? I know That if there is no view for this cannot return a view. but why returning a redirectToAction?

Comment: Because instead of returning a normal page you return a page with `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 174 ...`

Comment: [Wikipedia Article on url redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)